# Is there something similar to "keypad" without using "Curses"?

Tags: perl, console, terminal

Is there something similar to `keypad(1)` outside from [`Curses`](https://metacpan.org/module/Curses)?
I would like to write something like this, but without using `Curses` and without handling the escape sequences myself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Curses;

initscr();
raw();
printw( qq{Press "Delete"} );
noecho();
keypad(1); 
my $c = getch();
endwin();

if ( $c =~ /\A330\z/ ) {
    say "OK";
} else {
    say qq{You didn't press "Delete"};
}
```

When I use `Term::ReadKey` it behaves different:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode('raw');

print qq{Press "Delete" };
while ( 1 ) {
    my $c = ReadKey( 0 );
    last if $c eq 'q';
    say "<$c>";
}

ReadMode('normal');
```

Output after pressing "Delete":

```
Press "Delete" <
<[>
<3>
<~>
```

Comment: [Term::ReadKey](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Term::ReadKey) doesn't do it?

Comment: It does do it, but it is more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is it about Curses that you want to avoid?

You may find [Term::TermKey](https://metacpan.org/module/Term%3A%3ATermKey) useful. It is a Perl interface to the [libtermkey](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/) library, which handles keyboard control characters and multi-byte escape sequences and UTF-8 characters.

Comment: When I use `Curses` I don't see the part, that I have written to the console before using Curses, so I would have to write all with Curses.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin), [Term::TermKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::TermKey) may help:

```
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Term::TermKey;

my $tk = Term::TermKey->new( \*STDIN );

print qq{Press "Delete" };
while( 1 ) {
   $tk->waitkey( my $key );
   say "<", $tk->format_key( $key, 0 ), ">";
}
```

Gives

```
Press "Delete" <Delete>
```